# Is it possible to use eval() in React.js Native to define new experiences within an app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs

I'm considering writing a new mobile app using React.js native and I'd like to be able to tweak the UX post-launch as I A/B test, fix bugs, etc.

Are there any technical constraints that would make it impossible/difficult for the app to modify itself by downloading a bundle of JavaScript and eval()'ing it?

What about app store rules for iOS or Android?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. I'm doing that. There are also projects like https://github.com/aerofs/react-native-auto-updater.

Comment: Some of the issues include having to base64 images if you want to bundle them with the code. This also complicates development and changing of those images.